# Laravel echo not working with dynamically id

Tags: laravel, vue.js, echo, pusher, laravel-echo

I use pusher ,Laravel echo and vue.js to make chat just like  the picture
[the chat app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un4Bl.png)

Here is the vue.js code

```
var myChat = new Vue({
  el: '#myChat',
  data: { 
      the_chat: '', 
      current_user_id: 1,  
  },
  mounted(){
      this.set_user_id();
       window.Echo.channel( 'the_chat.'+this.current_user_id ) 
          .listen('SendMessage' ,(e) => {
            myChat.the_chat.push(e.chat);
            console.log('the_chat.'+this.current_user_id +'  -----');
      });
  },
  methods:{
     choose_user:function(user_id,model){
          $.get(api_get_chat+'/'+user_id,function(response){
              myChat.the_chat = response; 
              myChat.current_user_id = user_id; 
              console.log( myChat.echo_the_chat_id );
          });
      }
}
```

First when the `current_user_id = 1` it echoes channel `the_chat.1` only
but when `current_user_id` changed to `2` , it still echoes to channel `the_chat.1` only and in the `console.log`

> the_chat.2 ----

due to

```
console.log('the_chat.'+this.current_user_id +'  -----');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is more difficult as you think.

**First:** When you mount the component, this code runs `window.Echo.channel()` but only one time. When you change the Id variable, this code wont register again the channel listening.

**Second:** The console writes the modified ID variable because the log writer uses that refered variable, what is changed. (I hope you understand. :) )

**Solution:** you should move the ID variable changing logic to the parent component, and re-render / re-mount this component every id change event.
(Or ugly way: you should make a watch method on id, and whenever it changes, reregister the channel listening. But self re-mountning not a good way..)

I Hope it helps! :)